# Change Launch screen appearance (.dark/.light/.unspecified) based on app appearance settings SwiftUI iOS 13 with Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI application with a minimum supported version of iOS 13. I have an app appearance setting (Light/Dark/System default) which is working fine on the change of setting I'm overriding the window `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property with selected appearance and I'm storing the selected appearance setting in UserDefaults which I can use to set the appearance of the app on next launch. My issue is the appearance of my launch screen is always remains system default (e.g. Launch screen display in dark mode if the device is in dark mode and display in light mode when the device is set to light mode). I want to set the launch screen background based on my app appearance setting. I tried the following solutions but it doesn't work.

```
func handleAppearanceOnLaunch(){
        let mode = PrefrencesUtil.getInt(key: Constants.USER_SELECTED_APPEARANCE)
        var appearance = UIUserInterfaceStyle.unspecified
        switch mode {
        case 0:
            appearance = UIUserInterfaceStyle.unspecified
        case 1:
            appearance = UIUserInterfaceStyle.light
        case 2:
            appearance = UIUserInterfaceStyle.dark
        default:
            appearance = UIUserInterfaceStyle.unspecified
        }
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = appearance
    }
```

I am calling this method from the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.
I also tried calling the above method from `SceneDelegate`'s `willConnectTo` method but it is not working. After the launch screen app is following my app appearance setting only the launch screen is a problem. Please help me resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When setting up the Launch Screen storyboard, set the view "Background" color to "System Background Color". This will be white in light mode and black in dark mode. No need to use your own color asset.

Comment: @Kudos I'm doing the same and it is working fine with the device's appearance. I'm facing an issue when I set light appearance for my app and device appearance is dark launch screen displays in dark mode instead of light mode. I have setting options in my app to change the app appearance.